# SQL sum values from a column with values from an other colums based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, set, sql-update, sum

So I HAVE this Query where i have to update a table. IF the value exists in the table it should update only one column of the table, if it doesn't exists it should insert into the column.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT d1.IDComanda, d1.IDComandaPozitie,  sum(d1.Cantitate)  FROM   GEMsc2Pozitii as d1   
    WHERE    d1.IDComanda IS NOT NULL and d1.IDComandaPozitie is not null
    GROUP BY d1.IDComanda , d1.IDComandaPozitie 
    )
BEGIN
  UPDATE #ComenziCuPozActive  SET CantInchisa = CantInchisa + (SELECT sum(d1.Cantitate) from  GEMsc2Pozitii as d1   
    WHERE    d1.IDComanda IS NOT NULL and d1.IDComandaPozitie is not null 
    GROUP BY d1.IDComanda , d1.IDComandaPozitie  ) 

END
ELSE
BEGIN
  INSERT  INTO #ComenziCuPozActive 
  SELECT d1.IDComanda, d1.IDComandaPozitie, sum(d1.Cantitate) FROM   GEMsc2Pozitii as d1 
  GROUP BY d1.IDComanda , d1.IDComandaPozitie  
END
```

The problem is that SET CantInchisa can't take multiple values, which is logic. How can I sum 2 colums based on an condition.

Ex :

```
#ComenziCuPozActive a
IDComanda IDPozitie     CantInchisa 
1            1                2
1            2                1
2            2                4


GEMsc2Pozitii b

IDComanda IDComandaPozitie Cantitate
1            1                2
1            2                1
2            2                4
```

WHERE a.IDComanda = b.IDComanda and a.IDComandaPozitie=b.IDPozitie I want to sum the cantitate column.

```
RESULT 

  #ComenziCuPozActive a
    IDComanda IDPozitie     CantInchisa 
    1            1                4
    1            2                 2
    2            2                8
```

Comment: Consider using WHERE EXISTS (...) in the WHERE clause of your UPDATE statement.

Comment: I've managed to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

UPDATE #ComenziCuPozActive  SET CantInchisa = CantInchisa + d1.Cantitate FROM GEMsc3Pozitii d1 JOIN #ComenziCuPozActive x on d1.IDComanda=x.IDComanda and d1.IDComandaPozitie=x.IDPozitie

If anyone wonders.